# Getting multiple images from the SD Card to show up in Coverflow

Tags: android, image, external, sd-card, image-gallery

How to get multiple images to show up in this coverflow. I am getting null pointer exception and other problems. How to be able to load the images from the SD card, not knowing how many images are on the SD card? The number of images is not fixed.  I was able to get one image to show up with no problems by using this code:

```
i.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/pic03.png"));
```

it loaded one image, the one specified from the SD card and made all the coverflow images as that one same image, pic03.png,  about a dozen of the same one image filled the cover flow.  that is great, however i wanted to load all of the images on the SD card. so each image fills each part of the coverflow,  not one same image filling all of them.

totally lost here and tried to do this and got null pointer exception from the Logcat and wonder why?  does anyone know how to get this to work?

here below is the code that i am working with to give you some idea:
notice that it does work when loading one image from a specified address on the SD card. at least that part worked great,  but multiple images?

```
// added this code inside the onCreate method to load the cursor with images only if the IS_PRIVATE column
// in the sqlite database is equal to the integer 1 

String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
imagecursor = managedQuery(
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img,
MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE + "='" + 1 +"'",null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "");
image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
count = imagecursor.getCount();

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// ImageAdapter class is a nested class inside of the CoverFlowExample class

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Context mContext;
private FileInputStream fis;

// originally earlier version of this app loaded images from the R.drawable folder like this

private Integer[] mImageIds = {

  //  R.drawable.pic01,
  //  R.drawable.pic02,
  //  R.drawable.pic03,
  //  R.drawable.pic04,
  //  R.drawable.pic05,
  //  R.drawable.pic06,
  //  R.drawable.pic07,
  //  R.drawable.pic08,
  //  R.drawable.pic09
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// getView() method that is in the ImageAdapter class that extends the BaseAdapter class
// this class is a nested class inside the CoverFlowExample class that extends Activity.
// the CoverFlowExample class is used to implement the coverflow part of the app as an Activity

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // to load from resources like SD card
  ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

 // use for single image -->  i.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/pic03.png"));

 image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrowMediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
 imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);

 int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
 i.setImageURIUri.withAppendedPathMediaStore         .Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));

 // image from R.drawable use -->  i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
 i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
 i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);            
 return i;

  // return mImages[position];  <-- not using this as im am not getting image from R.drawable
}
```

Comment: STOP SHOUTING! IT MAKES YOUR QUESTION HARDER TO READ. They invented the shift key for a reason. Typing in all CAPS makes text harder to read, and will not improve the speed you get an answer.

Comment: I only had 5 words in my post that were in all caps,  but since you are sensitive to the inclusion of all capital case words, i am sure others out there are.  The intended purpose was to make the text more clear to read by emphasizing certain points, not for yelling.  but some disagree,  fair enough, if that is the culture here I have changed the 5 words to lowercase.  however i left the word "SD" card to uppercase as SD card is usually written that way.  anyway thank you for the comment.  Always wanting to improve my communication and fit in with the community here.

Comment: 90% of the subject of your original question was IN ALL CAPS, which is what I was referring to when I posted my comment. You can check the edit history to confirm. As far as emphasis, this site supports **bold** and *italic*, as well as `code formatting`, to do so; there's no need to type in CAPS for that purpose. `SD` is proper in upper case, as are `SDK` or `IBM` or `MS-DOS`.

Comment: you are correct. sorry about that.  i thought you were referring to written material in the post, not the title of the post.   the title was in all caps.   i will change it.  i am sure that people don't like to see that.  I am glad you took the time to point that out.  if nobody tells me what i am doing wrong I will never learn.    If i do anything else that is crazy, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems that `String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID }`
 this is the only column contained in the `imagecursor`, while you try to get the `DATA` column ,`imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrowMediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)`